# CRF model for Thai syllable segmentation doesn't work

Tags: python, nlp, torch, text-segmentation, crf

This CRF model that's supposed to segment Thai syllables doesn't work. I can't figure out why.
Everytime I input text, I usually get alternating sequence of B and I. For example, if I input "เหงา" the correct output should be "BIII" but instead I it outputs "BIBI". I've spent much time looking for problems but can't find one, thanks in advance for helping!

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from data.crf_segmentation import X_train, Y_train
from torchcrf import CRF
from utils import DataLoader, embed

embedded = DataLoader()
char_to_idx = {'<PAD>': 0,'<UNK>': 1}
tag_to_idx = {'<PAD>': 0}
for sent_tags in Y_train:
    for tag in sent_tags:
        if tag not in tag_to_idx:
            tag_to_idx[tag] = len(tag_to_idx)

X_train_idx = [[char_to_idx.get(char, char_to_idx['<UNK>']) for char in word] for word in X_train]
Y_train_idx = [[tag_to_idx[tag] for tag in word_tags] for word_tags in Y_train]

# print(char_to_idx)
# print(tag_to_idx)
print(X_train)
# print(X_train_idx)
# print(Y_train_idx)

class CRFModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_tags):
        super(CRFModel, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(68, num_tags)
        self.crf = CRF(num_tags, batch_first=True)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        emissions = self.linear(x)
        return emissions

num_tags = len(tag_to_idx)
model = CRFModel(num_tags)

criterion = model.crf
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)

num_epochs = 1000
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    
    for inputs, targets in zip(X_train, Y_train_idx):
        bruh = embed("one_hot", inputs, embedded).unsqueeze(0)
        print(bruh)
        targets = torch.tensor(targets).unsqueeze(0)
        print(targets)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(bruh)
        loss = -criterion(outputs, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        total_loss += loss.item()
    
    avg_loss = total_loss / len(X_train_idx)
    print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {avg_loss:.4f}")

while True:
    input_sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ").split()
    input_word = [(char)for char in input_sentence[0]]
    input_tensor = embed("one_hot", input_word, embedded).unsqueeze(0)

    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        emissions = model(input_tensor)

    with torch.no_grad():
        predicted_tags = model.crf.decode(emissions)

    print(predicted_tags)
    predicted_tags = [list(tag_to_idx.keys())[idx] for idx in predicted_tags[0]]
    print("Input Sentence:", " ".join(input_sentence))
    print("Predicted Tags:", " ".join(predicted_tags))
```